The ideal class group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{30})$
I wish to compute class group of $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{30})$. I have checked, using sage, that the group is $C_2$, but I have the incorrect answer of $C_2\times C_2$. I outline my line of reasoning below; I would appreciate some guidance on how to correct my approach. To save some reading, I seem to be making a mistake when it comes to checking if $P_2P_5$ is principal or not.
The Minkowski bound is $\sqrt30$, and so I've checked how the rational primes $2$,$3$ and $5$ factorise in $K$, with $\alpha = \sqrt30$
$$(2) = (2,\alpha)^2 = P_2^2$$
$$(3) = (3,\alpha)^2 = P_3^2$$
$$(5) = (5,\alpha)^2 = P_5^2$$
I have checked that these prime ideals are not principal. We see that the orders of all the elements in the class group are $2$, and $P_2P_3=(6+\alpha)$, so $P_2$ and $P_3$ are in the same ideal class. Since I should be getting a class group of order 2, I expect something similar to happen when computing $P_2P_5$, yet if this were to be principal, generated by $x+y\alpha$, say, then, since $N(P_2P_5) = 10$, we need integer solutions to:
$$x^2 - 30y^2 = \pm10$$
A number theoretic argument, or a check on Wolfram Alpha, shows that no such solutions can be found. This has led me to believe that $P_2$ and $P_5$ are not in the same ideal class (else, since the order of the ideal class is $2$, the product of the ideals would be principal), and hence that the class group is $C_2\times C_2$.

Looks like a copy from the question in the physics forum.

@DietrichBurde I did see this, but I wasn't sure if the question was answered. Indeed, the answerer seemed to suggest that $P_2P_3 = (30)$, which I believe is wrong?

For a correct proof see here, page $1$. So $p_2p_3=(6+\sqrt{30})$. Here $p_2^2=(2)$ and $p_3^2=(3)$, with $p_2=(2,\sqrt{30})$ and $p_3=(3,\sqrt{30})$. But $p_3\sim p_2^2p_3\sim p_3$, so that the class group has only two elements, namely $[(1)]$ and $[p_2]$.

@DietrichBurde I agree with this, but I'm currently only allowed to make use of the Minkowski bound ($\sqrt30$ in this case), so I had to look at how $(5)$ splits. I'm just troubled by my reasoning on $P_2P_5$ being non principal; surely I would expect it to be principal given the correct class group?

@DietrichBurde This is true, I completely forgot. I am unfortunately still not finding any algebraic integers in $K$ which have norm $\pm10$

there is a mapping,  two to one for real quadratic fields, from indefinite binary forms, group operation Gauss composition. The four classes of forms have (reduced)representatives  $x^2 +10xy - 5 y^2, ; -x^2 + 10 xy + 5 y^2, ; $  then $2x^2 +8xy - 7 y^2, ; -2x^2 + 8 xy + 7 y^2, ; $  and that's it. The first pair goes to an ideal, the second to another ideal. Just the two. It's in Cohen; also http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/BLOG_2014_July_15.pdf

Meanwhile, all   numbers representable by an indefinite such as $x^2 - 30 y^2$  may be found, and proved, by drawing a Conway Topograph   for the form. It is prettiest  if we draw $x^2 + 10 xy - 5 y^2$ instead.....

right, the positive values (primitively represented) along the "river"  are just $1,6.$   Climbing one level, new value $19.$   That's it, no $10$

and $5x^2 + 10 xy -  y^2$  starts $5, 14, 21,26,$  so there was no $-10$    either

@WillJagy So this mapping is from indefinite binary forms to class groups of real quadratic fields?

WE, yes, for real quadratic it is two to one.

@WillJagy Is there a similar mapping of PDBQFs to complex quadratic fields?

yes, in that case one to one. Here we need to take  form discriminant fundamental; if we multiply some discriminant $D$  by some square, the class number usually increases, while the field has not changed. This is all in Cohen, A Course in  Computational Number Theory.  Chapter 5 is Algorithms for Quadratic Fields, begins page 223. Fundamental Discriminant defined page 224; then section 5.2 is Ideals and Quadratic Forms.   I learned this material in D. A. Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms

*Note to self (and maybe others): $N((\beta)) = |N_{K|\mathbb{Q}}(\beta)|$, with a large emphasis on $||$
$P_5 = (5-\alpha)$, and so is principal.

put another way,  form $6x^2 - 5 y^2$  is integrally equivalent to $x^2 - 30 y^2.$  One can see how $6x^2 - 5 y^2$    represents the coefficient $1$  as $6-5$
